# How to increase the total issuance of tokens in the system?

Tags: substrate

When the first time I build and run the node-template , in the polkadot ui it Shows
"total issuance
4.6116 MUnit" and I want to increase this. how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically set some endowed accounts here. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L303

Or use root to mint some token in this system. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/lib.rs#L314

And there are still a lot of ways to do that. But all of them are done with pallet-balances.